# Dynamic indentation in devexpress aspxgridview

Tags: devexpress, indentation, aspxgridview

Are anyone aware of any method to achieve indentation in the ASPXGridView (we are running the 10.x version currently available)

What we got

[image]

What we'd like to achieve

[image]

Some information about the code-behind.

The grid is populated by an ObjectDataSource and the indentation is stored in a property alongside with the other data. In example the BMI row will have 0 indentation while the GENDER will have 1, and MAN will have 2. Etc...

The indentation is calculated runtime since relations might change.

```
public void GetItemsRecursive(int? parentId, int level)
{
    List<qstFeedbackLine> q;

    if (parentId == 0)
        q = _db.qstFeedbackLines.Where(x => x.ParentId == null).ToList();
    else
        q = _db.qstFeedbackLines.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId).ToList();

    foreach (var item in q)
    {
        // Store the indent
        item.Indent = level;

        // Add item to List
        _items.Add(item);

        level++;
        // ...and get the children of the current id
        GetItemsRecursive(item.FeedBackLineId, level);
    }
}
```

Any advice out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the ASPxTreeList component instead!

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxTreeListDemos/